# SFINAE for type instantiation

Tags: c++, sfinae

I came across the [Member Detector](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Member_Detector) idiom in C++, which is a type-trait to tell if a class contains a member of a certain name. But the linked example does not work as I expected if the type is not a class: I wanted a `false` result for any non-class type. A possible solution is certainly something like this, using `boost::is_class<T>`:

```
template<typename T>
struct general_DetectX : boost::mpl::and_<
    boost::is_class<T>,
    DetectX<T> >::type
{ };

bool hasX = general_DetectX<int>::value; // hasX = false
```

But this question is about why the original `DetectX<T>` produces errors instead of doing the SFINAE thing. Here is an excerpt of the relevant parts of the linked code (local structs `Fallback` and `Check<U,U>` and typedefs `ArrayOfOne`, `ArrayOfTwo` and `type` removed for brevity):

```
template<typename T>
class DetectX
{
      struct Derived : T, Fallback { };

      template<typename U> 
      static ArrayOfOne & func(Check<int Fallback::*, &U::X> *);

      template<typename U> 
      static ArrayOfTwo & func(...);

  public:
      enum { value = sizeof(func<Derived>(0)) == 2 };
};
```

It can be seen that `DetectX::Derived` is used outside of any overload resolution, so the SFINAE rule for handling errors is never invoked. But this can be changed to where use of `Derived` *does* happen as part of the overload resolution:

```
template<typename T>
class DetectX
{
    template<typename U>
    struct Derived : U, Fallback { };

    template<typename U>
    static ArrayOfOne & func(Check<int Fallback::*, &Derived<U>::X> *);

    template<typename U>
    static ArrayOfTwo & func(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(func<T>(0)) == 2 };
};
```

The `Derived<T>` template is only instantiated when trying to instantiate the first `func()` overload, so why do I still get errors even for the modified version? Here is an example:

```
$ g++ --version | head -n1
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2
$ g++ -c demo.cxx
demo.cxx: In instantiation of 'struct DetectX<int>::Derived<int>':
demo.cxx:16:53:   required by substitution of 'template<class U> static char (& DetectX<T>::func(DetectX<T>::Check<int DetectX<T>::Fallback::*, (& DetectX<T>::Derived<U>::X)>*))[1] [with U = U; T = int] [with U = int]'
demo.cxx:24:31:   required from 'class DetectX<int>'
demo.cxx:27:25:   required from here
demo.cxx:7:12: error: base type 'int' fails to be a struct or class type
     struct Derived : U, Fallback { };
            ^
```

Comment: It fails because the substitution happens in the list of base classes *where* any error results in hard-error as opposed to soft-error (SFINAE). In other words, SFINAE doesn't occur in base classes.

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks for the comment introducing me to hard vs soft errors. But I needed the link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260685 provided by Jarod42 in his answer to get the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use: (https://ideone.com/LArNVO)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

#define DEFINE_HAS_MEMBER(traitsName, memberName)                             \
    template <typename U>                                                     \
    class traitsName                                                          \
    {                                                                         \
    private:                                                                  \
        struct Fallback { int memberName; };                                  \
        struct Dummy {};                                                      \
        template<typename T, bool is_a_class = std::is_class<T>::value>       \
        struct identity_for_class_or_dummy { using type = Dummy; };           \
        template<typename T>                                                  \
        struct identity_for_class_or_dummy<T, true> { using type = T; };      \
                                                                              \
        template <typename Base>                                              \
        struct Derived : Base, Fallback {};                                   \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                                \
        template<typename T>                                                  \
        static std::uint8_t                                                   \
        check(helper<int (Fallback::*),                                       \
              &Derived<typename identity_for_class_or_dummy<T>::type>::memberName>*); \
        template<typename T> static std::uint16_t check(...);                 \
    public:                                                                   \
        static                                                                \
        constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint16_t);  \
    }

DEFINE_HAS_MEMBER(has_foo, foo);

// Now test it:
class C{ public: int foo; };
class D : public C {};
class E {};

static_assert(has_foo<C>::value, "");
static_assert(has_foo<D>::value, "");
static_assert(!has_foo<E>::value, "");
static_assert(!has_foo<int>::value, "");
```

You may understand why it fails in your case in following question [What is exactly the “immediate context” mentioned in the C++11 Standard for which SFINAE applies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260685/what-is-exactly-the-immediate-context-mentioned-in-the-c11-standard-for-whic)

In short SFINAE applies to `Derived<U>::X` but not to `Derived<U>` (which is ill formed in your case).

Comment: Thank you for the DEFINE_HAS_MEMBER example, but I can't use it in this application: 1. it uses C++11 but I use C++03 which I forgot to mention (minor: can be rewritten). 2. it needs a signature of the member, which the other solution does not need. But the link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260685 was really helpful, basically answering my question: instantiation of `Derived<U>` happens in the first step of instantiating `func<U>`, where SFINAE does not apply.

Comment: For *2.*, I have fixed my implementation. (as the signature for `T::foo` is not checked).

Comment: thanks I used your technique for exactly this case too.