# enable_if and mutually exclusive methods

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, enable-if

I can't understand why the following code is not working. compiler (gcc) seems to instanciate both
methods and obviously integer is either signed or unsigned, so one always fails. I though enable_if was here to avoid that.

Q: why the compile error, and how to avoid it ?

```
using namespace boost; // or std as you want

template<typename T>
struct test {
    // if signed
    template< typename enable_if
                        < is_signed<T>
                        , int
                        >:: type = 0
            >
    test &operator<<=(int value)
    {}

    // if unsigned
    template< typename enable_if
                        < is_unsigned<T>
                        , int
                        >:: type = 0
            > 
    test &operator<<=(int value)
    {}
};

void foo()
{
    test<int> x;
    x << 1;            // COMPILE ERROR no type named 'type' in struct enable_if<unsigned> etc.
    test<unsigned> y;
    y << 1;            // COMPILE ERROR no type named 'type' in struct enable_if<int> etc.
}
```

Comment: Define "it's not working". What happens? How does it differ from what you wanted to happen? We cannot magically divine your intention solely from a piece of code that, by your own admission, _does not represent that goal_.

Comment: added... but redundant with 'seems to implement both methods...'

Comment: Not "redundant" at all, no. We are scientists. We value _precision_ and _specifics_ and _data_. "Seems to implement both methods" is none of those things!!

Answer (score 5):

SFINAE is applicable only in an [*immediate context*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15260685/3953764) (SFINAE = SFIICINAE, *Substitution Failure In Immediate Context Is Not An Error*):

§14.8.2 [temp.deduct]/p8:

> Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type and its template parameter types can result in a deduction failure.

A substitution of class template parameters in a member function's declaration is not an immediate context, and results in *hard* error on failure.

You can either *partially-specialize* entire class depending on the type, or introduce an immediate context yourself by adding a template parameters to the member function template itself, so that a substitution failure can result in *soft* error:

```
template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<U>{}, int>::type = 0>
test &operator<<=(int value)
{ return *this; }

template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<U>{}, int>::type = 0>
test &operator<<=(int value)
{ return *this; }
```