# member function SFINAE error C2938

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfinae

This Code failed to compile in VS2013.

```
template<typename T>
class SomeClass {
public:
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T>
        DoSomething() {
        return T();
    }

    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T>
        DoSomething() {
        return T();
    }
};
```

How to make it work in VS2013(DoSomething must be non-static member function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFINAE only works on templates. Your `DoSomething()` is not a template, it's a non-template member of a class template. You need to make it a template:

```
template<typename T>
class SomeClass {
public:
    template <class U = T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental<U>::value, T>
        DoSomething() {
        return T();
    }

    template <class U = T>
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental<U>::value, T>
        DoSomething() {
        return T();
    }
};
```

[[Live example]](http://ideone.com/QCt1Bn)

Comment: I misunderstood something! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

> Only the failures in the types and expressions in the [immediate context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260685/what-is-exactly-the-immediate-context-mentioned-in-the-c11-standard-for-whic) of the function type or its template parameter types are SFINAE errors.

To get SFINAE in the resolution of `DoSomething`, you need to introduce an immediate context via another template parameter and check that it is `T`.

```
template<typename T>
class SomeClass {
public:
    template <typename U = T> 
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental<U>::value && std::is_same<U,T>::value, T>
        DoSomething() {
        return T();
    }

    template <typename U = T> 
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental<U>::value && std::is_same<U,T>::value, T>
        DoSomething() {
        return T();
    }
};
```

The `std::is_same` check is added to prevent someone calling `SomeClass::DoSomething<U>` with `U` being a type that isn't `T`.

Answer (score 2):

Tag dispatch feels better and cleaner than SFINAE for this:

```
template<typename T>
class SomeClass {
private:
    T DoSomethingImpl(std::true_type /*is_fundamental*/) { return T(); }
    T DoSomethingImpl(std::false_type /*is_fundamental*/) { return T(); }
public:
    T DoSomething() {
        return DoSomethingImpl(std::is_fundamental<T>());
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll use this one.