# C++ template instantations: using enable_if directly, or with an auxiliary class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enable-if

This code works fine:

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

enum class Type : char { Void };
struct FieldA { static constexpr Type type = Type::Void; };

template<typename Field> struct Signal {};
template<typename Field> struct SignalA : public Signal<Field> {};
struct SignalB : public Signal<void> {};
struct DerivedB : public SignalB {};

template<typename Signal, typename = void> struct Apply;

template<typename Field>
struct Apply<SignalA<Field>, typename std::enable_if<Field::type == Type::Void>::type> {};

template<typename Signal_t>
struct Apply<Signal_t, typename enable_if<is_base_of<SignalB, Signal_t>::value>::type>
{};

int main ()
{ Apply<SignalA<FieldA> > a; }
```

But what I want is improve readability erasing the long `enable_if`s, so, let's attack, for example, the second `enable_if` with an auxiliary class:

```
template<typename Signal>
struct IsBaseOfB
{ using type = typename enable_if<is_base_of<SignalB, Signal>::type; };
```

And change the second `Apply` partial specialization with it:

```
template<typename Signal_t>
struct Apply<Signal_t, typename IsBaseOfB<Signal_t>::type>
{};
```

Even when the only possible specialization is the first one, `gcc` throws me the following error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct IsBaseOfB<SignalA<FieldA> >':
main.cpp:21:78: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'

{ using type = typename enable_if<is_base_of<SignalB, Signal_t>::value>::type; };
```

Which is obvious since the `enable_if` condition doesn't fit for `SignalA<FieldA>`.

Which I don't understand is why that specialization failure is not ignored to get the first specialization (which I know it works).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is not in "the immediate context" of the template argument deduction, and so SFINAE does not apply (i.e. it's an error, not a substitution failure).

The C++ standard doesn't really define "immediate context" but I have attempted to give a hand-wavy explanation in the accepted answer to [What is exactly the “immediate context” mentioned in the C++11 Standard for which SFINAE applies?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261234/981959)

Briefly, the problem is that the compiler sees `Apply<SignalA<FieldA>>` and happily substitutes the template arguments into `struct Apply<Signal_t, typename IsBaseOfB<Signal_t>::type>` which happens without an error because `IsBaseOf` *does* have a nested `type` member, but then that triggers the instantiation of `IsBaseOf::type` and that's ill-formed. The error is not in the immediate context of the deduction (it's elsewhere in the body of `IsBaseOf` which is instantiated as a side effect).

Another way to look at the problem is that `IsBaseOf::type` is declared unconditionally, not only when the `is_base_of` trait is true, so it is always *declared* as a type ... but sometimes its *definition* is ill-formed. The deduction finds the declaration and continues past the point where SFINAE applies, then a fatal error is found when the definition of `IsBaseOf::type` is required.

You can either solve it using an alias template (as shown in Filip's answer) or using inheritance, so that `IsBaseOf::type` only exists conditionally:

```
template<typename Signal>
struct IsBaseOfB : enable_if<is_base_of<SignalB, Signal>::value>
{ };
```

This way the nested `type` member is only present when the `enable_if` base class declares it.

Comment: The problem with the `using` keyword is that it can't be used to instantiate dependent types (till C++17 though), so the inheritage approach is the best one now I think

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the alias template in the other answer should work in C++11

Answer (score 4):

#### Introduction

*SFINAE* only applies if the substitution error is in the *immediate context* of template instantiation, if the substitution error occurs in the body of said template the program is ill-formed.

- [What is exactly the “immediate context” mentioned in the C++11 Standard for which SFINAE applies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15260685/1090079)

---

#### Solution

Either you make the substitution error occur in the immediate context of the instantiation of `template<typename> struct IsBaseOfB`, or you simply define a *template alias-declaration* that will be equivalent to your rather lengthy trait.

<sub>**template alias-declaration** (recommended)</sub>

```
template<typename Signal>
using IsBaseOfB = enable_if<is_base_of<SignalB, Signal>::value>;
```

<sub>**using inheritance**</sub>

```
template<typename Signal>
struct IsBaseOfB
  : enable_if<is_base_of<SignalB, Signal>::value>
{ };
```