# C++, curious compiler error when implementing a function `int next(std::string param)`

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, msvc12

I've been badly bitten by the following code, on which I wasted many hours of precious time.

```
#include<string>

int next(std::string param){
    return 0;
}

void foo(){
    next(std::string{ "abc" });
}
```

This produces the following compiler error (on Visual Studio 2013):

```
1>------ Build started: Project: sandbox, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  test.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(371): error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
1>          c:\users\ray\dropbox\programming\c++\sandbox\test.cpp(8) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::iterator_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(371): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iterator_category'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(371): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(371): error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>::iterator_category' is not a member of a base class of 'std::iterator_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(371) : see declaration of 'std::iterator_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>::iterator_category'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility(371): error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>::iterator_category' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I found out later that if I change my function name from `next()` to something else, all is fine. To me, this indicates that there is a name conflict, specifically of the name `next`. I find this strange because I didn't use anything like `using namespace std`. As far as I know, `next` is not a built-in C++ keyword (is it?). I looked up `next` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), but it's `std::next` and as I said I didn't `using namespace std`. So how did this conflict happen? How do I prevent similar things in the future? What other names might cause a conflict like this?

Comment: Due to the way ADL can work, in my workplace we tend to always explicitly specify a namespace when we mean to call a very specific free function, even when we refer to the global namespace. In your case, it would be `::next(std::string{abc});`.

Comment: I just realized that `std::next("abc")` is legal and returns `"bc"`. ADL doesn't apply to string literals so `next("abc")` would depend on `using namespace std`.

Comment: @PiotrS. ADL took place because the call is unqualified, and it finds `std::next` because it's in an associated namespace of `std::string`. Just doing a qualified call as `::next` is likely to be more understandable to most people.

Comment: I just had a similar set of errors with trying to construct a vector with a list of its elements `return std::vector<Vec>(a,b);`, which of course does not work (but should just give an error like there-is-no-such-consructor).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are several things going on here, interacting in subtle ways.

Firstly, an unqualified call to `next` with an argument of type `std::string` means that as well as your own `next` function, the standard function template `std::next` is found by [Argument-dependent lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) (ADL).

After name lookup has found your `::next` and the standard library's `std::next` it performs overload resolution to see which one is a better match for the arguments you called it with.

The definition of `std::next` looks like:

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
  ForwardIterator next(ForwardIterator x,
  typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::difference_type n = 1);
```

This means that when the compiler performs overload resolution it substitutes the type `std::string` into `std::iterator_traits<std::string>`.

Prior to C++14 [`iterator_traits` is not SFINAE-friendly](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2408) which means that it is invalid to instantiate it with a  type that is not an iterator. `std::string` is not an iterator, so it's invalid.  The [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) rule does not apply here, because the error is not in the [immediate context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15260685/981959), and so using `iterator_traits<T>::difference_type` for any non-iterator `T` will produce a hard error, not a substitution failure.

Your code should work correctly in C++14, or using a different standard library implementation that already provides a SFINAE-friendly `iterator_traits`, such as GCC's library. I believe Microsoft will also provide a SFINAE-friendly `iterator_traits` for the next major release of  Visual Studio.

To make your code work now you can qualify the call to `next` so ADL is not performed:

```
::next(std::string{ "abc" });
```

This says to call the `next` in the global namespace, rather  than any other `next` that might be found by unqualified name lookup.

Comment: Lwg 2408 was applied after C++14 shipped.. alhough I suppose it can be seen as a DR that 14 compilers should implement.

Comment: @Cubbi, that was the intent of the committee, that's why the change was made as a DR not an N-numbered paper (which is how it was originally proposed).

Comment: OK I will have to read up later on SFINAE. What does it stand for? I'm just surprised that the compiler looked for a `next` that is "further away" and "more obscure" than the one that right in front of its eyes. But it's probably because I don't understand SFINAE.

Comment: No, it's because of ADL. Read the answer again. The compiler tries to find _all_ the possible overloaded `next` functions, and as well as your one ADL finds the "further away" one. Then the compiler tries to decide which of all the `next` overloads it found is the best one to call in this case, because that's how overloading works. The compiler  _should_ choose your one, but while trying to decide whether `std::next` should even be considered there is an error that stops compilation.. I linked to the Wikipedia page on SFINAE in my answer, which tells you what it stands for and what it means.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ah I see it's much clearer now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

(Updated per Jonathan's comments)
There are two views here, the C++11 and the C++14 view. Back in 2013, C++11's `std::next` was not properly defined. It is supposed to apply to iterators, but due to what looks like an oversight it will cause hard failures when you pass it a non-iterator. I believe the intention was that SFINAE should have prevented this; `std::iterator_traits<X>` should cause substitution failures.

In C++14, this problem is solved. The definition of `std::next` hasn't changed, but it's second argument (`std::iterator_traits<>`) is now properly empty for non-iterators. This eliminates `std::next` from the overload set for non-iterators.

The relevant declaration (taken from VS2013) is

```
template<class _FwdIt> inline
 _FwdIt next(_FwdIt _First,
 typename iterator_traits<_FwdIt>::difference_type _Off = 1)
```

This function should be added to the overload set if it can be instantiated for the given arguments.

The function is found via Argument Dependent Lookup and Microsoft's header structure. They put `std::next` in `<xutility>` which is shared between `<string>` and `<iterator>`

Note: `_FwdIt` and `_Off` are part of the implementation namespace. Don't use leading underscores yourself.

Comment: Prior to C++14 [`iterator_traits` is not SFINAE-friendly](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2408) so the error is not in the immediate context, and so it's expected (although annoying) that `iterator_traits<T>::difference_type` for any non-iterator `T` will produce a hard error not a substitution failure.

Comment: Ouch, this is painful. I wouldn’t have expected MSVC to get this wrong. Did you file a bug report yet? (Edit: oops, never mind, this comment is partly made obsolete with Jonathan’s comment; I still think that a report should be filed, although they are probably already tracking it internally somehow.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph, they didn't get anything wrong, their library is conforming to C++11 in this respect. The problem is the definition of `iterator_traits`, and that's why we fixed it in the  C++14 standard. I believe MS plan to update (or already have updated) `iterator_traits` to match the C++14 definition (which libstdc++ has done for years).

Comment: @Jonathan The fact remains that the `std::next` implementation should *not* lead to a conflict here. If `iterator_traits` isn’t SFINAE friendly then they’d need to take other precautions, don’t you agree? Even if the standard failed to state this unambiguously, OP’s code clearly shouldn’t break, regardless of other concerns.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, it's a quality of implementation issue. As written, the C++11 standard makes the OP's code ill-formed.

Answer (score 5):

Actually `std::next()` is a function defined in `<iterator>` which returns the next iterator passed to `std::next()`. Your code is running on my computer with gcc-4.9.2. More : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next

The code I used:

```
#include<string>
#include <iostream>
int next(std::string param){
    std::cout<<param<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void foo(){
    next(std::string{ "abc" });
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Also on ideone : http://ideone.com/QVxbO4

Comment: OK you're the second person to report that this is running fine on your computer. Maybe Visual Studio 2013 is implicitly `using namespace std`?

Comment: @Ray It’s almost certainly not. The fact of `std::next` being found via argument-dependent lookup does *not* necessarily mean that `using namespace std;` is in effect. It just means that the MSVC standard library implementation of `std::next` does not properly specify its arguments.

Comment: @mnciittbhu I understand your answer but I'm afraid you're not answering my question. You are `using namespace std`, and my question is why the compiler still thinks I'm using `std::next()` even though I'm not `using namespace std`. Your link is the same link I wrote in my question. I know about `std::next()`, as I said very clearly in my question.

Comment: @Ray even if `using namespace std;` (which doesn't happen here), the code should still be OK, as your `next` is a different overload, so there should be no ambiguity.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The actual problem appears to be a SFINAE failure. The library implementation is correct (I checked), but the failing template instantiation should just have been taken out of the overload set.

Comment: @MSalters, SFINAE doesn't apply because the error is not in the immediate context

Comment: @Ray I removed ```using namespace std``` and the program still runs fine.

Comment: @mnciitbhu, that's because GCC's library has provided a SFINAE-friendly `iterator_traits` for many years, even though that wasn't required by the standard until C++14.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler found standard function `std::next` due to the so-called Argument Dependent Lookup because the argument used in the call - std::string - is declared in namespace `std`.

Comment: The question is: is this correct? The code compiles fine on clang and gcc. `std::next` should in fact only be defined for iterators.

Comment: But I'm not `using namespace std`.

Comment: @Ray When unqualified name is used the compiler takes into account arguments and seeks also the function name in namespace where the arguments themselves are declared. In your case you use arguments of type std::string. Type std::string is defined in namespace std and the compiler finds the corresponding function., The other question is why the compiler does bot use your function. You should provide a ready to compile example that reproduce the error.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph The question why the MS VC++ compiler does not see the user defined function requeres additional investigation or at least a ready to compile example that reproduces the error.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the example I gave in my question is the ready-to-compile example that produces an error in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, it does see it, but `std::next` is found by ADL and added to the overload set, and performing overload resolution on `std::next` causes an error. See my answer for full details.

Comment: @onathan Wakely O'k. I think it is simply a bug of MS VC++ 2010.