# SFINAE not working inside decltype() when attempting to disable a no-args member function

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, enable-if

I have distilled the issue down to the following class which is attempting to use `std::enable_if` to disable a member function:

```
#include <type_traits>

int foo(int& x) {
    return x;
}

template<bool enable>
struct A {
int x;
template<bool dummy=true,
        typename Enabler = typename std::enable_if<dummy && enable>::type>
 auto disabled_method() const -> decltype(foo(x)) {

    return foo(x);
 }
};

int main() {
    A<false> x;
}
```

There is a type error in the expression `decltype(foo(x))`,  even though the function should be disabled by the `enable_if`!

Note that it is particular to occuring in the return type of the function.   For example, if we move the `decltype(foo(x))` to the body of the function, SFINAE will work fine:

```
template<bool dummy=true,
        typename Enabler = typename std::enable_if<dummy && enable>::type>
 auto disabled_method() const -> int {
    decltype(foo((X)x)) local;
    return foo(x);
 }
```

(Same for using `decltype(foo((X)x))` as an argument type)

Likewise, it will correctly perform SFINAE if I declare it as

```
template<bool dummy=true,
        typename X = const int,
        typename Enabler = typename std::enable_if<dummy && enable>::type>
 auto disabled_method() const -> decltype(foo((X)x)) {

    return foo(x);
 }
```

But using `decltype(foo((const int)x))`, it will error out, despite X being equal to `const int` above.  This seems to indicate that introducing the extra cast to the template parameter `X` causes it to delay the substitution.

But the `dummy` and `Enabler` template pattern up above is supposed to do that anyways?

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with "immediate context".

In general, errors in nondependent constructs render the program ill-formed NDR (no diagnostic required), see [[temp.res]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#8). Implementations have broad leeway to diagnose - or not diagnose - such problems.

In your case, `foo(x)` doesn't depend on a template parameter, and is always ill-formed; implementations are therefore free to diagnose it even if `A` is never instantiated.

Comment: If `foo(x)` does not depend on a template parameter then it is not in the immediate context?

Comment: @Curious That conflates two distinct sets of rules. In particular, it implies that the compiler can't ever treat such things as substitution failure.

Answer (score 1):

The return type is a part of the SFINAE process, this is why you can also include the `std::enable_if` as a part of the return type.  But SFINAE only works if there is an error in the immediate context, the `foo(x)` however is not a part of the immediate template context, therefore the compiler throws an error.

For example, if you change the code to be the following

```
template<bool dummy=true>
std::enable_if_t<dummy && enable, decltype(foo(x))> disabled_method()
        const {
    return foo(x);
}
```

Then the `enable_if` works, because not the `decltype(foo(x))` is a part of the `enable_if` itself and outside the immediate context where `x` is non-const

Take a look at this question and its answer for more information about what the immediate context is [What exactly is the "immediate context" mentioned in the C++11 Standard for which SFINAE applies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260685/what-exactly-is-the-immediate-context-mentioned-in-the-c11-standard-for-whic)

---

For your convenience, a quote from the linked question's answer that explains what the immediate context is

> If you consider all the templates and implicitly-defined functions that are needed to determine the result of the template argument substitution, and imagine they are generated first, before substitution starts, then any errors occurring in that first step are not in the immediate context, and result in hard errors.

In your example, the return type is needed to determine the result of the template argument substitution and is independent of the substitution process, hence it results in a hard error.

---

Also in such cases, I usually find it easier to leave out the return type entirely, and let the compiler deduce it.  It's much easier to work with.

Comment: Actually, the example you posted only works because x is non-const outside the context of the function definition.  This is clear if you switch the argument type of foo() to std::string.  (But I do know that you can get it to work if you use boost::lazy_enable_if).  I will take a closer look at your references, thank you!

Comment: I don't believe that "immediate context" explains this case, because the example with `foo((X)x)` is in exactly the same context, but works.  It seems to depend on whether the template parameters are used, not on the context.

Comment: @JeremySalwen  `foo((X)x)`  works because it is dependent on the template parameters which puts it in the immediate context of deduction, anything else is not in the immediate context.