# Selectively instantiate member functions of a template with SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae, crtp

So in a template class, I was trying to instantiate different member according to some information provided statically. In the below template, if some condition holds, the `selectiveMember` is contained within `SelectiveClass`, otherwise, the template is intended to be instantiated without `selectiveMember` but still contain `foo`.

```
template<typename T>
struct SelectiveClass{

  void foo(){...}

  template<condition_check<T>::type=0>
  void selectiveMember{...}
}
```

However, this kind of implementation would discard the whole class if condition is not satisfied. Nevertheless, using the CRTP technique, we can reach the purpose.

```
template<typename T>
struct SelectiveClass: Specialize<T>{   
  void foo(){...}
}
template<typename T>
struct Specialize{
  template<condition_check<T>::type=0>
  void selectiveMember{...}
}
```

But with this technique, each selective member would require another specialized  inheritance.

So my question is: Is there any more elegant way to allow this kind of selective member template?

Comment: You are asking for an elegant way to provide a functionality for some `T` only. Have you considered using a non-member function? In general, preferring free functions over dozens of member functions can also help to improve encapsulation etc. Some IMHO good arguments are presented in the talk [Free Your Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLDT1lDOsb4) by Klaus Iglberger.

Comment: @Julius I was using this technique to provide interface. How would you implement this with only free functions? Could you elaborate the idea?

Comment: The free function can look like this: `template<class T> void selectiveNonMember(SelectiveClass<T>& self) { /* extend the functionality of SelectiveClass<T> by using its member functions as building blocks */ }`.

Comment: could you provide an example of the `condition_check<T>` please?

Comment: @linuxfever something like `enable_if<is_integral<T>::value,int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your `enable_if` doesn't work the way you want it to, is because it is not used in the immediate context (see, for instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260685/what-exactly-is-the-immediate-context-mentioned-in-the-c11-standard-for-whic)). However, if you insert a default template argument in the `selectiveMember` function, you can achieve what you need. In the example below, I am using a concrete example of a `condition` but you can replace this with your own.

```
#include <type_traits>


template<typename T>
struct SelectiveClass{

  void foo(){}

  template <class X = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, X>* = nullptr>
  void selectiveMember(){}
};

using test_int = SelectiveClass<int>;
using test_double = SelectiveClass<double>;

int main() {

    test_int x;
    test_double y;

    x.selectiveMember();
//    y.selectiveMember(); fails to compile as expected
}
```

Comment: I think that is exactly where the problem is. Thank you.