# How to disable member functions using std::enable_if

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

What is the differences between these classes? Specifically, these member functions with `enable_if`.

```
/// Alias of std::enable_if...
template <bool B, typename T = void>
using Enable_if = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class A {
   ...
    template <std::size_t NN = N,
          typename = Enable_if<NN == 2>>
    Some_Return_Type
    method(param1, param2)
    {}

    template <std::size_t NN = N,
              typename = Enable_if<NN == 1>>
    Some_Return_Type
    method(param1)
    {}

};


template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class B {
   ...
    Enable_if<N == 2, Some_Return_Type>
    method(param1, param2)
    {}

    Enable_if<N == 1, Some_Return_Type>
    method(param1)
    {}
};
```

What is the correct way to use `enable_if` in the case I have:

- At least 2 methods that differs only in their arguments and they have the same name but just one of them must be "active" (if `N == 1` one of them, if `N == 2` the other).
- Only one method that will be active if `N == 0` and not active in other cases.

I would like to get something like:

```
Obj<int, 2> obj2;
Obj<int, 0> obj0;
Obj<int, 1> obj1;
```

if I write in the IDE `obj0.` it should show only methods of:

- `N == 0`;
- for `obj1.`, only `N == 1`
- ...

Comment: Which method do you want to be available for N==0?

Comment: As a note, C++14 added the library type alias `std::enable_if_t<bool, typename>`, which is equivalent to your `Enable_if`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that `enable_if` is aimed to trigger SFINAE: if a template parameter substitution fails in its *immediate* context, it is not a compilation error.

This is exaclty what happens in `class A`: when the user calls `a.method(...)`, the compiler attempts to instantiate member function template `method`, subsituting `NN` parameter with a constant, which might fail.

However, in case of `B::method` the "bad" substitution occurs during class template `B` instantiation, when the compiler substitues `N`. The failure occurs far from the parameter's immediate context, which is in this case `template<typename T, std::size_t N> class B`.

That's why in the second case you will get a compilation error, rather than SFINAE.

So, to enable/disable member functions depending on the *class template* parameter, use the first approach, combining conditions as you wish. For instance:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class A {
    template <std::size_t NN = N, typename = std::enable_if_t<NN == 2 || NN == 0>>
    void method(int, int)
    {}

    template <std::size_t NN = N, typename = std::enable_if_t<NN == 1 || NN == 0>>
    void method(int)
    {}
};
```

**UPDATE**: How enable_if works. Roughly, one can implement it like this:

```
template<bool, class T = void>
struct enable_if {};

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> {
    using type = T;
};
```

Note that if the first argument is `false`, `enable_if` doesn't have inner `type`, so `enable_if<false, int>::type` would be ill-formed. That's what triggers SFINAE.

Comment: The A class is the correct way to implement SFINAE, ok but I can't understand the second part. In A class if  `NN == 2` (or `NN == 1`) `Enable_if` return void to the second typename, so the method is "defined" and I can call it. What does it return when substitution fails? How can it disable the method? And I can't understand why I get an error in B class. Thanks and sorry :(

Comment: @Sam see my update about `enable_if` mechanism. As for your 2nd question, I tried to answer it: you get error in `B`, because it is not SFINAE: Substitution Failure Is Not An Error only when it fails in [immediate context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260685/what-exactly-is-the-immediate-context-mentioned-in-the-c11-standard-for-whic), wich is not the case with `B`.

Comment: The reason it fails for `B`, @Sam, is that it depends on _when_ the `enable_if` is evaluated.  Basically, SFINAE in layman's terms if "if we can't build it, chuck it away and find one we _can_ build."  In `A`, failure occurs when `method()` is called, because it depends on `method()`'s template parameters; this means that the compiler will examine every provided version of `method()`, in search of one that works.  For `B`, it depends on `B`'s template parameters, and thus the compiler examines every provided version of `B` for one that works.  But there's only _one_ `B`, so it can't find any.

Comment: (This, in turn, is because of when the templates are instantiated.  When you make an `A<int, 2>`, for example, the compiler will build it by filling in `A`'s template parameters wherever possible. In this case, that means filling in `method()`'s first template parameter's default value... but `method()` itself is still a template, and thus can't be compiled until it itself is instantiated or specialised (such as if you call `A<int, 2>::method()`, or define an explicit specialisation of `A<int, 2>::method<1>()`). Since the info isn't available until you use `method()`, SFINAE runs off `method`.

Comment: When you make a `B<int, 2>`, though, the compiler can fill in the `N`s in `method()`'s return types, causing it to see overloads `Enable_if<true, Some_Return_Type> method(param1, param2)` and `Enable_if<false, Some_Return_Type> method(param1)`.  The second is a substitution failure, meaning `B` is an invalid specialisation.  This, in turn, causes an error due to the lack of a valid specialisation of `B` for the template parameters, before `B::method()` can be involved in SFINAE.)

Comment: The disabled case for `std::enable_if` is an *empty* class, not an *incomplete* one.

Comment: @Deduplicator  why is it important? It would just affect the error message.

Comment: @IgorR. That's how it is specified, and code can depend on it.

Comment: @Deduplicator do you mean that the standard explicitly specifies that? I'd appreciate the relevant link...

Comment: ["*If B is true, the member typedef type shall equal T; otherwise, there shall be no member type*"](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.trans.other): Incomplete is a bit different from *no member*.

Comment: @Jan Schultke instead of changing my answer you could add your one.

Comment: @IgorR. it's not worth it. Your answer already explains it well, there are just some details that can be improved.