# C++ SFINAE for group of methods and decorators

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I have a std::variants containing objects with different interfaces. Goal is to call some of the methods if the object in variant has it.
I'm trying to make a couple of template decorators and looking for a way to do it with less boilerplate and without macro. 
Finally my idea looks like:

```
class Good
{
public:
    void a(int);
    float b(float);
    int c(double);
};

class Bad
{
public:
    void a(int);
    int c(double);
};

template<class T>
class View : protected T
{
public:
    using T::a;
    using T::b;
};
template<class T, template<class> class V>
constexpr bool IsFitToView = // ??
//usage

std::variant<Good, Bad> variant = //;
std::visit([](auto&& obj) {
    if constexpr(IsFitToView<std::decay_t<decltype(obj)>, View>)
    {
       View view{obj}; // create view from obj
       //here work with obj as view, calling a `a` and `b` methods;
    }
}, variant);
```

Main problem is how to create IsFitToView check. My approach is:

```
template<class T, template<class> class V, class = void>
struct IsFit : std::false_type
{};

template<class T, template<class> class V>
struct IsFit<T, V, std::void_t<V<T>>> : std::true_type
{};

template<class T, template<class> class V>
constexpr bool IsFitToView = IsFit<T, V>::value;
```

I had a hope that it has to work like SFINAE does: `View<Good>` compiles and template specialization selected, `View<Bad>` cannot be compiled because of `using T::b;` in a `View`.
But it returns true both for Good and Bad types!

```
std::cout << IsFitToView<Good, View> << IsFitToView<Bad, View>;
```

I know I can check the methods existence by a checking it indvidualy and check it like

```
if constexpr(HasAFunc<T> && HasBFunc<T> && ...
```

But I have to create many different `Views`. It is very verbose and hard to read.
Please, could you explain why my approach doesn't work and give any ideas to do what I want. 
Thanks!

Comment: The `View` body, including `using T::a;`, is outside of immediate context of `IsFit`.

Comment: Perhaps define [a concept for each view](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bbb15822acb48a7)?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reinvent `std::is_convertable` or to a lesser extent `std::is_invocable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Could you explain why my approach doesn't work ?*

Your current approach with `using` declarations fails, because the class' (`View`'s) body instantiation happens outside of [*immediate context*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15260685/3953764), which means it cannot result in a soft error that would result in falling back to the `IsFit` primary template, hence its specialization always produces a better match, resulting in `IsFitToView` always being `true`.

Even if that worked, `using T::a;` wouldn't tell you anything about `a`. It could be a single function, an overloaded set of functions, a `static` or non-`static` data member, or even an alias to some type that just happens to live in the `T`'s scope.

---

> *Could you give any ideas to do what I want?*

Knowing how to check for function existence, you could define views as variable templates, grouping general predicates, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool ViewAB = HasAFunc<T> && HasBFunc<T>;
```

With that, you just check:

```
if constexpr (ViewAB<std::decay_t<decltype(obj)>>)
```

---

Another solution is to use the [detection idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) form Library fundamentals v2:

```
template <typename T>
using ViewAB = decltype(std::declval<T>().a(3), std::declval<T>().b(3.14f));

template <typename T>
using ViewC = decltype(std::declval<T>().c(2.7271));
```

And use it like:

```
if constexpr (std::experimental::is_detected_v<ViewAB, decltype(obj)>)
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3780e09018de5f41)

---

Alternatively, in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), you could define views as concepts:

```
template <typename T>
concept ViewAB = requires (T t)
{
    t.a(1);
    t.b(3.14f);
};
```

Not only it makes the code easier to read and clearly presents requirements with sample usage, but also produces an error message explaining which constraint is not satisfied.

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9861a3bd717612e)