# std::enable_if is generating error when used on functions of same name inside a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, class-template

**Problem description**

I am trying to call a function that returns `1` or `2` depending on whether the type is `signed char` or `unsigned int`.

For this purpose, I wrote the following code. If I compile the code without the code inside the `main`. I get no compilation error.

But when I compile the code with the instantiation of an object `Coverage`, I get the following compilation errors:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Coverage<unsigned char>’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',27)">main.cpp:27:28</span>:   required from here
main.cpp:12:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if’
     int getNb(typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value, void>::type) {
         ^~~~~
main.cpp:17:9: error: invalid parameter type ‘std::enable_if::type {aka void}’
     int getNb(typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value, void>::type) {
         ^~~~~
main.cpp:17:9: error: in declaration ‘int Coverage::getNb(typename std::enable_if::value, void>::type)’
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:28:18: error: ‘class Coverage’ has no member named ‘getNb’
   std::cout << c.getNb() << std::endl;
```

I understood that when we add `typename std::enable_if` as function argument it's not taken into consideration. It is also the only way to use when we have member functions with the same name.

---

**Source Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Coverage
{
public:
   Coverage(T type) :_type(type) {}

   // signed char 
   int getNb(typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value, void>::type) {
      return 1;
   }

   // unsigned int
   int getNb(typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value, void>::type) {
      return 2;
   }

private:
   T _type;
};

int main()
{
   Coverage<unsigned char> c('c');
   std::cout << c.getNb() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not how SFINAE works. For SFINAE, you need a function template.

Comment: In addition to what @Evg said, have a look for **["immediate context"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260685/what-exactly-is-the-immediate-context-mentioned-in-the-c11-standard-for-whic)** requirement of SFINAEing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Evg mentioned you have to need the member function to be templated as well.
In addition, you need to provide default values for them, like usual `nullptr` defaulting.

[See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/enWsn4)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Coverage {
public:
   Coverage(T type) :_type(type) {}

   //signed char 
   template<typename Type = T> // templated the member!
   int getNb(typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<Type>::value, void>::type* = nullptr) 
   {
      return 1;
   }

   //unsigned int
   template<typename Type = T> // templated the member!
   int getNb(typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<Type>::value, void>::type* = nullptr)
   {
      return 2;
   }
};
```

---

Or provide a [trailing return](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/11/trailing-return-types-everywhere/) SFINAE for each functions

[See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6zxKhE)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Coverage {
public:
   Coverage(T type) :_type(type) {}

   template<typename Type = T>
   auto getNb() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<Type>::value, int>::type
   {
      return 1;
   }


   template<typename Type = T>
   auto getNb() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<Type>::value, int>::type
   {
      return 2;
   }

private:
   T _type;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The standard revision tag was not specified, so let me add a C++20 solution:

```
int getNb()
requires std::is_signed_v<T> {
    return 1;
}

int getNb()
requires std::is_unsigned_v<T> {
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: this is beautiful simple and easy. I wish I had C++20

Comment: And of course, then combine the two function in one by `if-constexpr` since C++17. `int getNb() {   if constexpr (std::is_signed_v<T>)   return 1;   else   return 2;   }`. No SFINAE required. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution in these kinds of cases is to use a helper class that's easily specialized, and implement the method in the helper class, or have the helper class invoke the real method in the original template, via a passed-in `this` pointer. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<bool> class coverage_helper;

template<>
class coverage_helper<true> {

public:

    template<typename T>
    static auto invoke_nb(T *this_p)
    {
        return this_p->get_nb_signed();
    }
};

template<>
class coverage_helper<false> {

public:

    template<typename T>
    static auto invoke_nb(T *this_p)
    {
        return this_p->get_nb_unsigned();
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Coverage{
    public:
    Coverage(T type):_type(type) {}

    int getNb()
    {
        return coverage_helper<std::is_signed<T>::value>::invoke_nb(this);
    }

    int get_nb_signed()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int get_nb_unsigned()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    private:
     T _type;
};

int main()
{
  Coverage<unsigned char> c('c');
  std::cout << c.getNb() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If C++17 is an option, you could avoid `std::enable_if` and make use of `if constexpr` instead.

```
template<typename T>
class Coverage {
   // ...
   static constexpr int getNb() {
        if constexpr ( std::is_unsigned_v<T> )
            return 2;
        else 
            return 1;
   }
   // ...
};
```

You could even make it a static member variable, instead of a function

```
template<typename T>
class Coverage {
    // ...
    static constexpr int Nb{ std::is_unsigned_v<T> ? 2 : 1 };
    // ...
};
```