# Use of variable template in concept contraints yields compilation errors

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following concept:

```cpp
template< typename T, std::size_t Value >
concept Is_ = requires(T&&)
{
    requires Value == std::remove_cvref_t< T >::value;
};
```

Associated with the function overloads:

```cpp
template< Is_< 2 > T >
void foo(T&&)
{
    std::cout << "Value is 2!" << std::endl;
}

template< typename T >
void foo(T&&)
{
    std::cout << "Either no value or it isn't 2!" << std::endl;
}
```

Finally, let's play with the above functions:

```cpp
foo(std::integral_constant< std::size_t, 2 >{}); // Choose the constrained overload
foo(std::tuple{}) // Choose the generic impl
```

Now if I define the following helper variable template:

```cpp
template< typename T >
inline constexpr auto t_value = T::value;
```

And use it in the concept for brevity's sake:

```cpp
template< typename T, std::size_t Value >
concept Is_ = requires(T&&)
{
    requires Value == t_value< std::remove_cvref_t< T > >;
};
```

I now get this compiler error:

> main.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr const auto t_value':
>
> main.cpp:11:23:   required by substitution of 'template  requires  Is_<T, 2> void foo(T&&) [with T = int]'
>
> main.cpp:27:8:   required from here
>
> main.cpp:6:29: error: 'value' is not a member of 'int'
>
> 6 | constexpr auto t_value = T::value;

Having invalid type aliases is however perfectly fine.

MVCE is available here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/653bb52448ca1db3

Where does this behavior come from?

Comment: If I uncomment the line marked with error this still works fine. (gcc13.1) Maybe your compiler haven't implemented everything from c++20?

Comment: Great example of a MCVE that does not match the code in the question.

Comment: Removing the type check reproduces the error. I edited the link in the question to reflect that.

Comment: See also [Why does GCC succeeds on a constraint with std::tuple_size::value, but fails on one with std::tuple_size_v?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68143642/636019)

Comment: Oh that's absolutely on point @ildjarn thank you (you might even say that my question is a dupe of the linked one, it's just that I couldn't find it with my wording)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because the instantiation of the variable template is not in the "immediate context" of the concept when it is being substituted and verified. Invalid types and expressions are only (and always have been) sfinae-friendly in the immediate context of the template argument substitution where they appear.

And since `t_value` is entirely different template, any failure that would occur during its instantiation would not be a "soft failure" in a concept that uses one of its specializations.

---

By the way, to address the original link in your post. Alias templates have special provisions that oftentimes allow them to be a drop-in replacement where whatever they are aliasing would appear (think how `std::enable_if_t` is also sfinae friendly, and always has been). When you checked the `t_value_type` alias in the conecpt before the value, it already failed in a sfinae-friendly way, so the concept evaluated to false (since the constraints were checked in order of appearance).

Comment: And "failing" type aliases are fine because they are sfinae-friendly, is that correct?

Comment: @Rerito - Yup, just added a note to that effect.

Comment: Alright, it's even clearer. This is what I suspected but I couldn't explain why the variable template wasn't sfinae friendly. That's perfect thank you!