# Concept requirement and non-immediate context

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm learning C++ concepts, and trying to realize why [the following does not compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/S0zUoN5IPZQ6be09) (it's just a trivial and meaningless example demonstrating the point; tested with GCC-11.1):

```
#include <iostream>

struct non_negatable {
};

template <class T>
auto negate(T a) {
    return -a;
}

template <class T>
concept is_negatable = requires(T t) {
    //just `-a;` would do the job of course
    negate(t);
};

template <class T>
auto do_negate(T) {
    std::cout << "here we are\n";
}

template <is_negatable T>
auto do_negate(T t) {
    return negate(t);
}

int main() {
    non_negatable x;
    do_negate(x);
}
```

The above concept attempts to call a function template, whose *implementation* would not compile. This fact causes a "hard error", rather than failing the concept.

I guess it works this way because the concept requirements may be failed only by the expressions' "immediate context" ill-formness (like what we could observe with SFINAE).

Is my understanding correct? Where does the Standard describe this point? Is there a way to "fail" a concept based on a function template implementation ill-formness?

Comment: "*Is there a way to "fail" a concept based on a function template implementation ill-formness?*" I'm afraid not, don't you think the overhead is too heavy if the compiler needs to check the specific implementation of the function?

Comment: In addition, definition might not be visible...

Comment: @Jarod42 shouldn't all the specializations of that template be available at the instantiation point of the concept?

Comment: Explicit instantiation might be done elsewhere. declaration should indeed be visible for concept, (and it is currently sufficient).

Comment: @康桓瑋 @Jarod42  but it *does* compile the definition from within the concept `requires` (take a look at the error messages "stack"), it just generates a hard-error, instead of failing the concept.  The following requirement still generates hard error: `std::declval<decltype(negate(t))>() + t;`

Comment: Maybe you should constrain `negate` for [starters](https://godbolt.org/z/d7e8csnn1).

Comment: I though the concept won't instantiate the function (but it seems it would [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MMabTvnTj)) and just succeeds (as from declaration `negate(std::declval<non_negatable>())` is valid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as you referred, `negate<non_negatable>` is not a substitution failure since the error is not in the [immediate context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260685) of the function, as such it's ill-formed. From [13.10.3.1/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct#general-8) of C++20 standard:

> If a substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type deduction fails.
>
> An invalid type or expression is one that would be ill-formed, with a diagnostic required, if written using the substituted arguments.
>
> [Note 4: If no diagnostic is required, the program is still ill-formed.
> Access checking is done as part of the substitution process.
> — end note]
>
> Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type, its template parameter types, and its explicit-specifier can result in a deduction failure.
>
> [Note 5: The substitution into types and expressions can result in effects such as the instantiation of class template specializations and/or function template specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined functions, etc. Such effects are not in the “immediate context” and can result in the program being ill-formed.
> — end note]

Secondly, [7.5.7.1/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.req#general-6) says:

> [...]
>
> [Note 1: If a requires-expression contains invalid types or expressions in its requirements, and it does not appear within the declaration of a templated entity, then the program is ill-formed.
> — end note]
>
> [...]

So, your understanding seems correct to me. However, what you're asking in your last question boils down to whether there is a way to make an invalid expression in a template function body cause a substitution failure instead of an ill-formed program. I don't think it's possible.