# Why this example results in "substitution failure" not "hard error"

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

Per [[temp.deduct]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#8):

> [..]
>
> **Only invalid types and expressions
> in the immediate context of the function type, its template parameter
> types, and its explicit-specifier can result in a deduction failure.**
>
> **[ Note: The substitution into types and expressions can result in
> effects such as the instantiation of class template specializations
> and/or function template specializations, the generation of
> implicitly-defined functions, etc. Such effects are not in the
> “immediate context” and can result in the program being ill-formed. —
> end note ]**

What I understand from the bold part is,

1. If the substitution process has side effects (such as instantiation of a template, etc), invalid types/expressions can result in a hard error.
2. If the substitution process *does not* have side effects, invalid types/expressions can result in a deduction failure.

If I right about what I saying above, why this program results in substitution failure and not hard error:

```
template <class T> struct S { using type = T; };
template <class> void f(...); // "fallback".
template <class T> struct A {};
template <class T> typename S<T>::type::type f(int); 
    
int main(void){

  f<A<int>>(0); // calls fallback. Why?
}
```

The above call substitutes `A<int>` with `T`. So the function type will be `S<int>::type (int)`. Now it has to instantiate the template `S<int>` to check the existence of the member `type`. And here is the point of my question: The substitution process has side effects that result in an invalid type because `S<int>` specialization has no members called `type`. So I am expecting that the program is ill-formed instead of calling `f(...)`.

---

I deliberately do not mention anything about the "*immediate contexts*" because I do not completely understand what this context involves/means even though there's a specific question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15260685/19696076) about it, but neither answer there mentions what exactly this context means. So, if possible, any side note about it will be appreciated.

Comment: See a very similar example given here; [What exactly is the "immediate context" mentioned in the C++11 Standard for which SFINAE applies?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261234/12002570)

Comment: @JasonLiam - _"Becasue return type in the given example is in immediate context."_. How do you know that?

Comment: There are two instantiations of class templates required for the overload resolution: Instantiation of `S<A<int>>` and of `A<int>`. Neither of these instantiations fail. There is nothing in the definition of `S` or `A` that would yield an invalid type when the template argument is subsituted. `S<A<int>>::type::type` or equivalently `A<int>::type` is however invalid, but that type is referred to only in the function template declaration, which is immediate context of the substitution of the function template's template argument (it appears in the return type, part of the type of the function).

Comment: `f<A<int>>(0); // calls fallback. Why?` because when compiler makes the list of function candidates to call, it rejects template functions which instance results in an ill-formed program, and your code still has a function to fallback to (another candidate). As simple as that

Comment: @TheDreamsWind "_it rejects template functions which instance results in an ill-formed program,_": It specifically only rejects them if substitution in the immediate context yields an invalid type or expression as quoted by OP. It does not reject it if instantiation of the function template or other required templates outside the immediate context results in a construct that is ill-formed. That's the distinction OP is asking about.

Comment: @user17732522 -  What I am expecting is that if the substitution process has side effects (here requires instantiation of `A<int>`)  such side effects can result in a hard error (and it has hard error because `A<int>::type` is invalid type). Am I correct?

Comment: @Morise Basically *"even though the instantiation of `A<int>` and `S<A<int>>` is not in the immediate context but `S<A<int>>::type::type` is. And since the instantiations `A<int>` and `S<A<int>>` are well-formed by themselves but `S<A<int>>::type::type` is not and since `S<A<int>>::type::type` is in immediate context, we get deduction failure instead of hard error "*.

Comment: "_such side effects can result in a hard error_": Yes, but it is not the instantiation of `A<int>` that is ill-formed here. It is the attempt to look up the `type` member inside the instantiated `A<int>`. The lookup is not part of the instantiation process (e.g. if you wrote a variable `A<int> a;` which also implicitly instantiates `A<int>` there would be no error). The lookup happens only in the function return type, i.e. "_immediate[ly in the] context of the function type_" in the quote in the question.

Comment: @user17732522 i'm not quite following which part is outside of immediate context here. `S<T>::type::type` is right there and since [synthesized function template specialization would be ill-formed, no such function is added to the candidate set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). If it was `S<T>::type` when it would be a candidate

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Yes sure. The invalid type here is in the immediate context. But "_which instance results in an ill-formed program_" is pretty much ignoring the difference between immediate context and what is outside of it (e.g. instantiations of `S<A<int>>` and `A<int>` which are however well-formed here).

Comment: @JasonLiam - _"instantiation of `A<int>` and `S<A<int>>` is not in the immediate context but `S<A<int>>::type::type` is."_ What do you by _is in the immediate context_? appears in the function type?

Comment: @Morise The whole expression `S<A<int>>::type::type` is part of the function template's **declaration** and so it is in the immediate context of the function template's substitution.

Comment: @Morise If you are trying to find an exact definition of what is meant by _immediate context_, you won't really find one. It is not properly defined but in most cases the note after your quote should be enough to give an idea of what is meant, see [CWG issue 1844](http://wg21.link/CWG1844) (and others).

Answer (score 1):

> So I am expecting that the program is ill-formed instead of calling f(...).

In the given example, both instantiations `A<int>` and `S<A<int>>` are well-formed by themselves. Now, even though the instantiation of `A<int>` and `S<A<int>>` is not in the immediate context of function template's substitution but `S<A<int>>::type::type` is.

Thus, we get a deduction failure corresponding to the expression `S<A<int>>::type::type` instead of getting a hard error corresponding to the instantiations `A<int>` and `S<A<int>>`.

---

If on the other hand, any of the instantiation were ill-formed then we would have gotten a hard error.

Comment: Can you simply tell me _why_  `S<A<int>>` is not in the immediate context and `S<A<int>>::type::type` is in the immediate context?

Comment: @Morise Because it is given in the text(note) that you have in your question from the standard. In particular, where it says: *"The substitution into types and expressions can result in effects such as the **instantiation of class template specializations**... **Such effects are not in the “immediate context**...”"*

Comment: .. so otherwise (i.e there are no such effects)?

Comment: @Morise Basically, the whole expression `S<A<int>>::type::type` is not an instantiation but only the subexpression `S<A<int>>` and `A<int>` are. That is, the instantiation is only `A<int>` and `S<A<int>>` and not `S<A<int>>::type::type`.

Comment: So you mean, if `S<A<int>>::type::type` yields invalid type, then this "invalid type" **is** in immediate context. Right?

Comment: _"the whole expression S<A<int>>::type::type is not an instantiation..."_ - OK the "whole expression" is just a type. Now let me know if this type is an "invalid type", then this type (the whole expression) is in immediate context. Right?

Comment: @Morise Yes, `S<A<int>>::type::type` is invalid and this is in immediate context.