# Deleted function template in requires-expression, differing compiler behavior

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, requires-expression

Consider a function template `f<T>` with the primary template deleted but some specializations defined. We can use a requires-expression to test if `f<T>` has been specialized:

```
template <typename T>
int f() = delete;

template <>
int f<int>() {
    return 1;
}

template <typename T>
int g() {
    if constexpr (requires { f<T>; }) {
        return f<T>();
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main() { return g<void>(); }
```

Version 1 ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/1rMaTjMc9)), same as above: compiles on clang but not gcc or msvc.

Version 2 ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/cGEsxhjfW)): replacing `requires { f<T>; }` with `requires { f<T>(); }` it now compiles on gcc as well.

Version 3 ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/oqKvaWdqo)): replacing the inline requires-expression with a named concept, it now compiles on all three compilers.

I am curious which of these versions are well-formed C++20 code and which instances represent compiler bugs.

Comment: Seems a little odd, when you could just have the primary template return -1, then you wouldn't even need the `if constexpr` anymore: `template <typename T> int f() { return -1; } ... template <> int f<int>() { return 1; } ... template <typename T> int g() { return f<T>(); } ...  int main() { return g<void>(); }`

Comment: That is true. In my actual use case, I was doing a compile-time loop over many possible `f<T>`, where only a few `f<T>` were actually implemented. When I had a default body in the primary template, the compiler was generating that code repeatedly. I wanted to avoid this.

Comment: if you try to use `f<int>`, then suddenly only msvc accept the code. https://godbolt.org/z/P34eWK18W

Comment: @appleapple that code is not using `f<int>`, though.  It is using `f<void>`, which is `delete`'d. MSVC compiles that code because it is optimizing out the usage. The code is not *calling* `f<void>()`, it is only *referring* to `f<void>` by name, which decays into a pointer to the function. The pointer is not being used for anything, thus *can* be optimized away, which MSVC is doing (and issuing a warning), but gcc and clang are not doing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ah yes my typo. it's `f<void>`, just like what OP put inside `require` expression.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think compiler can optimize ill-formed program and ignore the error. (unless it's NDR, of course)

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes then it's merely different behavior of that expression, not `require` expression. I just recheck the outout (of first link in question), and find gcc *report an error* on `require` expression and \*also\* compile the `constexpr` body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, MSVC is definitely wrong. It thinks the *requires-expression* is actually true. But [[dcl.fct.def.delete]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.delete#2) says:

> A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly, other than to declare, it, is ill-formed.
> [*Note 1*: This includes calling the function implicitly or explicitly and forming a pointer or pointer-to-member to the function.
> It applies even for references in expressions that are not potentially-evaluated.
> For an overload set, only the function selected by overload resolution is referenced.
> The implicit odr-use ([basic.def.odr]) of a virtual function does not, by itself, constitute a reference.
> — *end note*]

The expression `f<T>` is an lvalue that refers to the deleted function, so it "refers" to it; this is ill-formed and it should be detected by the *requires-expression*.

The only question is whether the ill-formedness is actually in the immediate context. The standard doesn't explain what "immediate context" means, but going off [the commonly understood meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261234/481267), the issue is whether the ill-formedness is the instantiation of the deleted `f<void>` (which would not be in the immediate context) or the reference to that deleted function (which would be in the immediate context). I'm inclined to go with Clang here: the instantiation itself is not ill-formed, because its effect is to instantiate `f<void>`, *i.e.*, synthesize the *definition* of that specialization (and a definition is a declaration), rather than *refer* to it.

Comment: fwiw, gcc report an error on `requires { f<T>; }` but evaluate false for `requires { f<T>(); }`.